# Converting from WriteableBitmap to Mat for then showing it in a window with CvInvoke.Imshow?

Tags: c#, kinect, emgucv

I'm fetching infrared frames from a Kinect V2 camera. The frames come in the form of WritableBitmap, so I try to convert it with this code that I made:

```
public Mat WritableBitmapToMat(WriteableBitmap writeBmp)
{
    Bitmap bmp;
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)writeBmp));
        enc.Save(outStream);
        bmp = new Bitmap(outStream);
    }

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

    IntPtr data = bmpData.Scan0;

    int step = bmpData.Stride;

    Mat mat = new Mat(bmp.Height, bmp.Width, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, 4, data, step);

    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    return mat;
}
```

I don't know if it's a problem with the conversion, but when I try to show the image in a window with this code:

```
CvInvoke.Imshow("window showing a picture", infraredMat);
```

I end up getting an exception that looks like this:

Exception: Exception thrown: 'System.AccessViolationException' in Emgu.CV.World.dll ("Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.").

I also want to mention I am using EmguCV 3.1 and Kinect SDK 2.0

Thanks in advance for any help I get.

Comment: Have you tried using unsafe code/method? Because you are accessing the memory bits directly so that might be an issue.

Comment: I know that the checkbox that says: "allow unsafe code" is checked. Should I add unsafe infront of my method as well?

Comment: I tried adding unsafe infront of my method. Didn't work, sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the InfraredBasics-WPF example in the Kinect 2.0 SDK, the IR images are fetched into a `ushort` vector from the `FrameReference.AcquireFrame()`method. Then you can use the `IntPtr infraredBuffer.UnderlyingBuffer` to access the frame data (in an unsafe method) to get the 1-D vector. You can later convert a 1-D to 2-D matrix if required using the standard 2xfor loops.

This way you won't have to access the data from the `BitmapEncoder. Plus, since it's given as a standard example in the SDK, it's the recommended method for getting the IR frames I think. Furthermore, the example also contains the method for displaying the IR images; unless you have a specific method/reason to use your way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! The only reason I wanted to do it this way is to be able to analyse them with EmguCV commands. That doesn't mean I know what I'm doing, as I started with learning about kinect and emgu about 3 weeks ago.

Comment: I actually haven't worked on EmguCV, but your post has got me interested in looking into it :) I'm no C# expert, but I think you could try getting the data from the AcquireFrame or reader_FrameArrived methods which fetch the image for use in further processing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! I'll try that. I'll post an update if I manage to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap in C# can be easily converted into Mat of EMGUCV by using the following codes:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("FilePath");//Declare a Bitmap Object
Image<Bgr, Byte> bmp_I = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bmp);//Creating an Image object in EMGUCV which can read Bitmap object.
Mat converted_mat = bmp_I.Mat;//Convert Image object into Mat
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method with good success:

```
    public static Mat ToMat(BitmapSource source)
    {
        if (source.Format == PixelFormats.Bgra32)
        {
            Mat result = new Mat();
            result.Create(source.PixelHeight, source.PixelWidth, DepthType.Cv8U, 4);
            source.CopyPixels(Int32Rect.Empty, result.DataPointer, result.Step * result.Rows, result.Step);
            return result;
        }
        else if (source.Format == PixelFormats.Bgr24)
        {
            Mat result = new Mat();
            result.Create(source.PixelHeight, source.PixelWidth, DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
            source.CopyPixels(Int32Rect.Empty, result.DataPointer, result.Step * result.Rows, result.Step);
            return result;
        }
        else if (source.Format == PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
        {
            Mat result = new Mat();
            result.Create(source.PixelHeight, source.PixelWidth, DepthType.Cv8U, 4);
            source.CopyPixels(Int32Rect.Empty, result.DataPointer, result.Step * result.Rows, result.Step);
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Conversion from BitmapSource of format {0} is not supported.", source.Format));
        }
    }
```

You can tweak this as needed. I am not sure if ImShow will deal with a BitMap of 32bit floats. Bitmaps, typically, are full of bytes. I could be wrong but I have never tried to get anything to show that are floats.

Doug